# Redshift SQL - Extract numbers from string

Tags: sql, regex, data-conversion, amazon-redshift

In Amazon Redshift tables, I have a string column from which I need to extract numbers only out. For this currently I use

```
translate(stringfield, '0123456789'||stringfield, '0123456789')
```

I was trying out REPLACE function, but its not gonna be elegant.

Any thoughts with converting the string into ASCII first and then doing some operation to extract only number? Or any other alternatives. 
It is hard here as Redshift do not support functions and is missing lot of traditional functions.

Edit:
Trying out the below, but it only returns 051-a92 where as I need 05192 as output. I am thinking of substring etc, but I only have regexp_substr available right now. How do I get rid of any characters in between

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('somestring-051-a92', '[0-9]+..[0-9]+', 1)
```

Comment: Better to parse it before putting into Redshift - more functionality, better performance, lower cost...

Comment: @Guy "more functionality, better performance, lower cost..." Huh? Have you ever looked into the cost of most analytic databases (Teradata, Vertica, et al)? Redshift is **cheap** and the SSD nodes are _fast_.

Comment: @JoeHarris, I agree that Redshift is very low cost, but it doesn't mean that you should fill it up with long textual columns. If you can parse them into more analytical form (numbers, categories, dates...), it is more scalable and cost effective.

Answer (score 2):

Better method is to remove all the non-numeric values:

```
select REGEXP_replace('somestring-051-a92', '[^0-9]', '')
```

Comment: If you wanted the *opposite* of this, i.e. remove all numbers from your string, you can use the following:

`REGEXP_REPLACE(your_column_or_string, '[0-9/-]', '')`

Comment: how would you do that if you want a float back? Like 98.76

Comment: select REGEXP_replace('somestring-98.76', '[^0-9.]', '')

Answer (score 1):

might be late but I was solving the same problem and finally came up with this

`select REGEXP_replace('somestring-051-a92', '[a-z/-]', '')`

alternatively, you can create a Python UDF now

Comment: REGEXP_replace(value, '[A-Z/-]|[a-z/-]')

Comment: wouldn't work with special characters

Answer (score 0):

Typically your inputs will conform to some sort of pattern that can be used to do the parsing using `SUBSTRING()` with `CHARINDEX() { aka STRPOS(), POSITION() }`.

E.g. find the first hyphen and the second hyphen and take the data between them.

If not (and assuming your character range is limited to ASCII) then your best bet would be to nest 26+ `REPLACE()` functions to remove all of the standard alpha characters (and any punctuation as well).

If you have multibyte characters in your data though then this is a non-starter.

Comment: What if I have multibyte characters in there?

Comment: Ha, it's a non-starter! If you really have multi-byte chars then these probably should have been split upstream somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

You can specify "any non digit" that includes non-printable, symbols, alpha, etc.

e.g., regexp_replace('brws--A*1','[\D]')

returns
"1"